# Error: Repository not found , Por favor asegurate de tener los accesos correctos?

Tags: github

Creando mi repositorio en github ejecute los codigo en el orden 
`git add .` , `git commit -m 'un commit`, pero a la hora de querer subir mi codigo al repositorio remoto con el comando `git push -u origin master` me arroja un error , es la primera vez que subo mi codigo a github pero no puedo debido a este error a que se debe,

```
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

al poner el comando `git remote -v` me arroja

```
origin git@github.com:emeery/alimento.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:emeery/alimento.git (push)
```

Comment: Estas seguro de que tu repositorio tiene ese nombre? https://github.com/emeery/feed no es ese? o tal vez este? ->  https://github.com/emeery/producto

Comment: estas con otra cuenta, debes acceder a tu git con tus datos, nombre y password

Answer (score 1):

El repo no existe, prueba a agregar como origen alguno de estos:

https://github.com/emeery/producto
https://github.com/emeery/feed

Dependiendo de a cual hagas referencia con `emeery/alimento`

Answer (score 1):

Puedes ver que repositorio remoto tienes asociado a tu repo local con:

```
git remote show origin
```

si no es el correcto puedes cambiar tu repositorio remoto bien con:

```
git remote remove origin
git remote add origin http://github.com/emeery/nombre-repo.git
```

o con:

```
git remote set-url origin http://github.com/emeery/nombre-repo.git
```

Tu primer *push* sincroniza ambos y debería ser:

```
git push -u origin master
```

Answer (score 0):

Intenté de varias maneras pero encontré la solución con estos dos comandos 
`git push origin master --force`  y  `git push origin master -f`